# Any breaking differences between AutoShardedBot and a regular Bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm in the middle of re-writing my Discord Bot, and I would like to know the differences between an AutoShardedBot and a regular Bot.

I've searched the documentation and more and couldn't find anything that gives a list of differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AutoShardedBot` inherits from [`AutoShardedClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AutoShardedClient) as well as `Bot`. The differences can be found in the documentation for that class, and include different implementations of `close`, `request_offline_members`, and `change_presence`.